# Vote form with selection dependant radio buttons or checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

Right now I'm trying to get along with a vote form in a way similar to Eurovision Songcontest Votes, eg you have a couple of things to choose for but only a fixed number of options to choose from where each option can only be used once. Based on that I like to deactivate the other radio buttons featuring the same value.

A simple example (with radio buttons since I'm not sure if it makes a difference using radio buttons or check boxes):

You get to vote how much points you like to spend for someone but can only spent either 1, 2 or 3 points for 3 persons in total. Checking the radiobutton for 2 points for the first person automatically disables the radio buttons for "2 points" for person 2 and person 3 so only "1 point" and "3 points" can be spent.

I hope that example was really of a simple one and look forward to help :)
Also I have to admit I had a real hard time finding similar threads, hence appearing as a new question here. Thanks in advance for participating!

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far. Judging from your post there's not much, but I do urge you to include HTML with the setup you want to use. This will help us to further understand what you're after.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Currently I have not tried anything as I want to have a working concept first. Of course I could set up a form and make it look like I want but that would not reflect what I'm after which is the codewise how to make those "unique" selections possible. I suspect that is being done with javascript but honestly I have no idea, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: To make only one radio button selectable (let's say you have three with represents choices to the same question: A) 12, B) 12, C) 12) give them the same name, this way only one should be able to be selected at one time. Use this and try to set up a prototype of what you want to do. From there we could develop the idea further into what you're after.